# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments problem

Tags: xcode, swift5

im stuck on this one thing

ive tried every thing

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

func  buttonpressed(_ sender: Any) {

    lightOn.toggle() {
        if lighton {
            view.backgroundcolor = .white
        } else {
            view.backgroundcolor = .black
        }
    }
    var view = true
}

var lightOn = true;
var toggle = true
```

Comment: What issue are you having? So far you have only told us you have an issue and shown us the code in question.

Comment: @matt I'm attempting help a new contributor learn how to ask questions in a clear way for the future.

Comment: @matt you and I both know that the issue is he is passing a closure to `toggle()` and it doesn't take any arguments including closures but that may not be clear to everyone and future questions may not be as clear. It is better to specify what error Xcode is producing when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
lightOn.toggle() {
```

makes no sense. The curly brace at the end of the line is meaningless junk. The compiler is so confused by it that it spits out an unhelpful error message.

Just say `lightOn.toggle()` and *stop*. That is the end of the command. If you then have more to do, go on to another line.

```
lightOn.toggle() 
if lightOn {
    view.backgroundColor = .white
} else {
    view.backgroundColor = .black
}
```

Comment: Also please note that Swift is case sensitive. You cannot say both `lightOn` and `lighton` to refer to the same thing. And `backgroundcolor` is not `backgroundColor`. Be accurate, both when programming and when giving code in Stack Overflow. Always copy and paste _real code_ in Stack Overflow.